# glassfish3.1.2.2: com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.UnsupportedSignatureMethodException: anymethod

Tags: oauth, glassfish, jax-rs, netbeans-7

I tried to implement jersey-oauth with the following environment:
glassfish 3.1.2.2 with Netbeans 7.3 as IDE
jersey 1.17 which I manually upgraded jersey jars on glassfish/modules
jersey-oauth 1.17

The JaxRS resources worked fine until the code tries to call

> com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthSignature.getSignatureMethod()

The last line resulted in this exception:

> com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.UnsupportedSignatureMethodException: HMAC-SHA1
>     at com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthSignature.getSignatureMethod(OAuthSignature.java:257)
>     at com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthSignature.verify(OAuthSignature.java:124)

So I thought HMAC-SHA1 might not be correctly supported. Then I used other Methods, non of them succeeded.

Please anyone help? Did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who come against this problem.

As I said, I tried to upgrade jersey version on glassfish. But I realized that it didn't take effect because there is osgi-cache.

To make sure that changes to the jersey jars take effect, it is recommended that /glassfish/domains/youdomain/osgi-cache folder should be deleted while the server is not running.

No need to worry about this folder because it will auto-generate on the next server start up.